# Switch View in form - using panel c#

Tags: c#

Using buttons to change the view of form Projects. 
As you see, there will be a lot of text in each button.

```
private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
      panel1.Visible = true;
      panel2.Visible = false;
      panel3.Visible = false;
      panel4.Visible = false;
    }
```

So made a method of it. Still feels very clumsy.. Is there a better way to switch the view of each panel?

```
    private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      panel = 1;
      PanelW(1);
    }

    public void PanelW(int panel)
    {
        if (panel == 1)
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel2.Visible = false;
            panel3.Visible = false;
            panel4.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (panel == 2)
        {
            panel2.Visible = true;
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel3.Visible = false;
            panel4.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (panel == 3)
        {
            panel3.Visible = true;
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = false;
            panel4.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (panel == 4)
        {
            panel4.Visible = true;
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = false;
            panel3.Visible = false;
        }
```

I dont want to use tabcontrol. Not sure if better using return value to button also, instead of void.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a many way to do this for example :

```
public void PanelW(int panel)
{
    foreach (var pb in this.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
        pb.Visible = pb.Name == "panel" + panel;
}
```

or use linq like as :

```
public void PanelW(int panel)
{
    Controls.OfType<Panel>().Count(p => (p.Visible = p.Name == "panel" + panel));
}
```

*Note : proposition 1 and 2 work if you named your Panels as the question (panel1, panel2, panel3, panel4 ..)*

or simply if you did not alot of Panels

```
public void PanelW(int panel)
{
    panel1.Visible = panel == 1;
    panel2.Visible = panel == 2;
    panel3.Visible = panel == 3;
    panel4.Visible = panel == 4;
}
```

Comment: Very nice!  Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Just off the top of my head, you could sub class Panel and add a property to it then use a for loop to set visibility based on that property. Sub-classed panel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

    public enum PanelType
    {
        HomeScreen, Settings
    }
    public partial class CustomPanel : Panel
    {

        public PanelType PanelType { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And then the method to switch panels:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SwitchPanel(PanelType.HomeScreen);
        }

        private void SwitchPanel(PanelType displayType)
        {
            foreach (var ctl in this.Controls)
            {
                if (ctl.GetType() == typeof(CustomPanel))
                    ((CustomPanel)ctl).Visible = ((CustomPanel)ctl).PanelType == displayType;
            }
        }
```

You will then need to replace your existing panels with custom panels (or whatever you call them) and then in the designer, on each panel set it's panel type.